# Saving a hash to the DB that contains arrays of the forms submitted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a form that saves the values into hashes. And from the controller the hash is saved to the db.

Here is the form

```
   <%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key1]' %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key2]' %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key3]' %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key4]' %>
     <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

   <% end %>
```

Here is where the hash is saved to the DB

```
  if @page.update (category_params)
   @page.update(table_content: params[:content])
   redirect_to show_pages_path(@category, @page)
   flash[:success] = "Updated."
   else
   render 'edit'
  end
```

I need to change the form so the value in the hash will be an array. And from the form the user can add items to the value array.

This is what the info is saved as to the db currently

```
{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3", "key4"=>"value4"}
```

and I need it to change to this

```
{"key1"=>["value1"], "key2"=>["value2"], "key3"=>["value3"], "key4"=>["value4"]}
```

So ultimately something like this is possible to be saved to the db from the form and through the controller

```
{"key1"=>["value1a","value1b"], "key2"=>["value2"], "key3"=>["value3a", "value3b"], "key4"=>["value4"]}
```

I will be using js so the user can add and remove inputs but I first need to know what the form setup will be like before I start on that.

For now for simplicity what would the form and maybe controller need to look like to save the bottom hash to the DB.

What part of `'content[1]'` needs to be changed so I can have another input add to the key `key1` value array.

I cant find how to have the inputs save as arrays let alone how to have 2 inputs save to the same key as part of an array.

Basically what would need to be done to save the third array listed to the DB from changing the form and controller I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take an array of your name in the form,

```
content[key1][]
```

```html
   <%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key1][]' %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key2][]' %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key3][]' %>

     <%= text_field_tag 'content[key4][]' %>
     <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

   <% end %>
```

Comment: How would the user add more than one value to one array? (preferable from a second input field)  `<%= text_field_tag 'content[key1][]' %>` I imagine would make the hash value an array with a single value inside that array. If i add `<%= text_field_tag 'content[key1][]' %>` again to the form I imagine it would just overwrite the first inputs value not add to the array assigned to `key1`.